# Where to add_filter in theme functions.php?

Tags: filters

I am new to Wordpress and want to make some changes in the content of a plugin page. I have found out that the same can be done using

[add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter)

I have the filter value for the plugin content that I want to change. I am using the storefront theme. So I open the storefront_functions.php , but I am not sure where to add the code snippet.

Seeking guidance/suggestions regarding the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every ***New*** function you should add to the bottom. Same with JavaScript, JQuery, CSS and any other language. Same as you would write in a book.

We only go back up to edit/amend something.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it would be the best to add at the bottom of the script, to make sure everything you use inside the snipped is declared already and ready to use.
It all depends on the actual code you're using and your goal.